# How to bundle Python apps with asset dependencies for end users?

Tags: python, bundle

I have a Tkinter app that uses images included in the same folder as the `.py` file. `pyinstaller script.py` produces an executable that runs but does not open any windows. This is because it is looking for images that don't exist in the same subdirectory. When I copy the important images to the `dist` folder Pyinstaller creates, the application runs correctly.

However, I would like to have a single executable that I can share with other users that doesn't also require them to have the images stored. The images should be bundled with the software somehow, like how commercial software (usually) doesn't require you to download assets separately from the program itself.

**Is there a way to bundle Python programs *and the assets they use* into single-click applications?**

Note that I am using Python 3 on Linux Mint. I am also something of a novice, so don't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I've solved my own problem.

Instead of having the images included in the same folder as `main.py` and using the resulting short relative filepath to reach them, install the images in an appropriate space in the system directory tree (I used `/home/$USER$/.$PROGRAMNAME$/`) and have the program access the files using the absolute path to that directory. This will allow you to copy the program anywhere on your computer you want and have it run without a problem.

However, if you want to share it with someone else, you'll need to also include an installation script that places the assets in the correct directory on their computer.